# Solve $2(x+1)y' = y$ using Power Series.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Given the ODE:

$2(x+1)y' = y$

How can I solve that using Power Series? I started to think about it:

$
\\2(x+1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{nc_nx^{n-1}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_nx^n}=0
\\2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{nc_nx^{n}}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{nc_nx^{n-1}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_nx^n}=0
\\\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2nc_nx^{n}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2(n+1)c_{n+1}x^{n}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_nx^n} = 0
\\\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{[2nc_n + 2(n+1)c_{n+1} - c_n]x^n} = 0
$

Then:

$
\\2nc_{n}+2(n+1)c_{n+1}-c_n=0
\\c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n(1-2n)}{2(n+1)}
$

Now, I should know what is the generic formula of $c_n$, but I can not see the pattern by assigning values to $n$. How can I proceed?

Comment: You should have $c_n$, not $c_{n+2}$ in the next to last equation, but it is fixed in the last.  Also the last term there should be $c_n$, not $cn$.  Your approach is good.

Comment: There is a pattern. I prefer $-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2n-1}{n+1}$. Let $c_1=a$. Then $c_2=a(-1/2)\frac{1}{2}$, So $c_3=a(-1/2)^2 \frac{1\cdot 3}{(2)(3)}$. Do not simplify! So $c_4=a(-1/2)^3 \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{(2)(3)(4)}$. Do not simplify. And so on. The numerator $1\cdot 3\cdot 5$ can be prettified by writing it as $\frac{6!}{2^3\cdot 3!}$.

Comment: Could you explain why did you say: The numerator $1 \times 3 \times  5$ can be prettified by writing it as $ \frac{6!}{2^3\times 3!}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you are given an initial value $f(0)=c_0$ (notice that this value corresponds exactly with the value of $c_0$ in the series). Then, as you have already worked out:
$$c_n = c_{n-1}(-1)\frac{1}{2}\frac{2n-3}{n}$$
and so on going down to $n=0$, thus:
$$c_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\frac{\prod_{k=0}^n(2n-3)}{n!}c_0$$

Comment: Is there some way to avoid using that productory?

Comment: @Richard I don't think so... I also tried to find a closed form for the final function, but didn't get anywhere. Notice that having the first few terms is enough to get a very good approximation of the function around $0$, though (wichh is what you need in some contexts).

Comment: If $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^nc_n}$, could it be a binomial serie? Something like: $c_0(1+x)^{1/2}$. Could it be related?

Comment: @Richard Well, it should be, since the solution to the ODE is $y(x) = c_0(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$... You can try to show that the expansion of this function around $0$ gives you the series of coefficients of above.

Comment: Could you try to show it?

Answer (score 1):

We can cheat and solve the ODE using separation of variables. The general solution for $x>-1$ is
$$y(x)=c_0\sqrt{\mathstrut1+x}\ .$$
Using the formula for the binomial series therefore gives
$$y(x)=c_0\sum_{k=0}^\infty{1/2\choose k}x^k\ .$$
Of course the numbers $a_k:={1/2\choose k}$ can be written in terms of factorials, if desired.